# Unable to detect the flaw in angular2+ code for dropdown

Tags: angular, user-interface, drop-down-menu, neo4j

I am using angular2+ template. And i want to create a drop-down. It was not available in the template (creative-tim template angular2). Kindly let me know what is the error in my code that i am not getting the drop-down.
Purpose is i am trying to integrate Angular2 + and NodeJS with Neo4j application.

Code -

**sidebar.component.html**

```
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
    <li   routerLinkActive="active" 
    *ngFor="let menuItem of dashboardMenuItems" class=" nav-item nav- 
          dropdown"  appNavDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#" 
       appNavDropdownToggle [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
            <i class="now-ui-icons {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
            <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
        </a>


        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
          <li class="nav-item">

            <!-- System -->

            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
           [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> System</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Interface -->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
      [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i class="fa fa-th"></i> Interface</a>
          </li>

          <!-- User -->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
       [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i class="icon-user"></i> User</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Group -->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
       [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i class="fa fa-group"></i> Group</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Role -->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
     [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Role</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Transaction -->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" 
      [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
              <i ></i>Transaction</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>


   </ul>
 </div>
```

Photo -

[image: Drop-Down Image]

Comment: your code does not seem to have drop-down? why and where are you expecting it?

Comment: I want it below in Century Dashboard i.e.  below <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>. With menuItem.title which is Century Dashboard  be the parent element. And rest all like System, Interface, User, etc...its drop-down Items.